# When keyboard appears, scrollview does not autoscroll for Entry

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I am working on xamarin.forms portable cross platform having two projects android and iOS.

When I keep cursor on Entry, keyboard open but scroll-view does not work

Below is my code

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource FillGrid}">
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<commonViews:CustomNavBar Grid.Row="0" Title="Add Journal"  IsImageVisible="False"/>
<ScrollView Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
  <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource StackLayoutHeaderStyle}">
      <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelHeaderStyle}" Text="Customer"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource StackLayoutEntryStyle}">
      <Views:CustomCombobox x:Name="cmbItem" PlaceHolder="Select Customer" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer
                  Tapped="OnItemTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
      </Views:CustomCombobox>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource StackLayoutEntryStyle}">

  </Grid>
</ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

in MainActivity.cs

```
    [Activity (
    Label = "App",
    Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
    Icon="@drawable/icon",
    MainLauncher = false, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan)
```

Please suggest where I'm wrong.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161379/xamarin-forms-android-keybord-does-not-scroll-the-list

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working.still same issue