# In grid Layout how to scroll page when keyboard open in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am facing one issue in xamarin.forms. I am using GridView to make login page design so it can be change accordingly device height and width. I don't want scroll that page So I didn't put any ScrollView.

Xaml Design Code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<custom:KeyboardResizingAwareContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HRMS.Login.LoginPage"
             BackgroundImage="login_bg.png"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HRMS;assembly=HRMS"
                   Title="{x:Static local:AppResources.TitleLogin}"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:HRMS.Login;assembly=HRMS">
  <ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Phone="60,40,60,40" Tablet="120,100,120,100" />
  </ContentPage.Padding>
  <custom:KeyboardResizingAwareContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="SubTitleStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </custom:KeyboardResizingAwareContentPage.Resources>
  <custom:KeyboardResizingAwareContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="AbsMain">
      <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="ImgLogo" Source="login_logo.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
          <StackLayout.HeightRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="55" Phone="35" />
          </StackLayout.HeightRequest>
        </StackLayout>
        <Frame OutlineColor="#DCDCDC"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"
            HasShadow="false" Padding="1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            Margin="5,0,5,0">
          <Frame.HeightRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="55" Phone="35" />
          </Frame.HeightRequest>
          <Frame.Content>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Image x:Name="ImgLoginName" Grid.Column="0" Source="ico_login_name.png"
                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
              <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Entry x:Name="TxtUsername" TextColor="#f15a23"
                       Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       PlaceholderColor="#8c8c8c"
                       BackgroundColor="White"
                       Placeholder="{x:Static local:AppResources.PHEmployeeCode}" />
              </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
          </Frame.Content>
        </Frame>
        <Frame OutlineColor="#DCDCDC"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"
            HasShadow="false" Padding="1"
            Grid.Row="3"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            Margin="5,0,5,0">
          <Frame.HeightRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="55" Phone="35" />
          </Frame.HeightRequest>
          <Frame.Content>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Image x:Name="ImgLoginPassword" Grid.Column="0" Source="ico_login_password.png"
                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
              <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Entry x:Name="TxtPassword" IsPassword="True" TextColor="#f15a23"
                     PlaceholderColor="#8c8c8c"
                     Margin="5,0,0,0"
                     BackgroundColor="White"
                     Placeholder="{x:Static local:AppResources.PHPassword}" />
              </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
          </Frame.Content>
        </Frame>
        <Label x:Name="LblForgotPassword" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,0,5,0"
                    Text="Forgot Password?" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.BLogin}" Clicked="LoginButton_Clicked"
                  Grid.Row="5" BackgroundColor="#f15a23" TextColor="White"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Button.HeightRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="55" Phone="45" />
          </Button.HeightRequest>
        </Button>
        <Image x:Name="ImgOr" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               Source="or.png" />
        <Button x:Name="BtnUpdateDevicewithlogin" Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.BUpdateDevice}"
                Clicked="UpdateDeviceWithLoginButton_Clicked" Grid.Row="7"
                BackgroundColor="#f15a23" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Button.HeightRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="55" Phone="45" />
          </Button.HeightRequest>
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actIndicator2" Color="#f15a23" Opacity="2"
              HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>

  </custom:KeyboardResizingAwareContentPage.Content>
</custom:KeyboardResizingAwareContentPage>
```

[image]

[image]

I am using "KeyboardResizingAwareContentPage" page instead "ContentPage" because In ios Page is not set when keyboard is open. password field hide behind keyboard so users can not see whatever then typing. That's why I am using Render for content Page in IOs.

**As Above images when I focus on username or password entry field two buttons are hide behind the keyboard. Client requirement is that at that time page should be scroll. How can I solve this problem? Is it possible through rendering? I am facing this issue in both the platform. (ios and android)**

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172518/how-do-i-keep-the-keyboard-from-covering-my-ui-instead-of-resizing-it

Comment: Place your grid inside the ScrollView in ContentPage

Comment: Yes, Remove appCompact

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't mean to scroll your page, use a ScrollView as the root of your Page, and put your grid in it.

This should fix it.

Comment: Its not working. (I am using Grid because my page design should be set as per device height. Page not scroll by any cost but now client requirement is page should be scroll when keyboard open). I am giving height to each row in " * " and Auto format. If I put my grid inside Scroll view My Grid getting confuse how much height it should take. So my design is improper.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by using Android platform-specific feature serves the purpose of configuring the operating mode for a soft keyboard input area. In XAML, you can apply it by assigning a value from the WindowSoftInputModeAdjust enumeration to the Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust attached property.

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
  ...
</Application>
```