# ListView moving on Keyboard activation in IOS xamarin forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with Entry and ListView in Xamarin Forms. On Android, it works perfectly but on IOS when Focus is set on Entry, ListView will be moved up like on the image:

[image]

I tried to use a render:

[How do I keep the keyboard from covering my UI instead of resizing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172518/how-do-i-keep-the-keyboard-from-covering-my-ui-instead-of-resizing-it)

but it didn't solve a problem, in my case because I need ListView moved not the whole page! I also found that this was a known issue:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45336

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xwDRT_CnoM&feature=youtu.be

Any suggestions how to turn off moving elements when the keyboard is activated?
And I need Focus set to true in this case!

The code in XAML is next:

```
<myControls:MyEntry Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource EntryControlStyle}" 
x:Name="CityEntry" AutomationId="SearchCityEntry" 
                       Placeholder="{Binding TravelType,  Converter={StaticResource LanguageConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                       Text="{Binding Path=SearchQuery}" />

<myControls:MyListControl
Grid.Row="1"
SeparatorVisibility="None"
HasUnevenRows="True"
IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
x:Name="SelectCity"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResults}"
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}">
 <myControls:MyListControl.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <ContentView BackgroundColor="White">
            <Grid Margin="10,10,0,10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                             VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                           Source="{Binding LocationSource,Converter={StaticResource LocationSourceEnumToImageConverter} }" />
                </StackLayout>

                <Label Grid.Column="1" AutomationId="SearchCityList"
                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       Style="{DynamicResource EntryControlStyle}" />
            </Grid>
        </ContentView>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

and code behind:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {            
        base.OnAppearing();
        CityEntry.Focus();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        CityEntry.Unfocus();
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        CityEntry.Unfocus();
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with your code. And your videos are in other case, you can try to record your own videos to show your problems. Moreover which iOS version are you using.

Comment: @ Land Lu - MSFT Thanks for your commitment and help! I succeeded to solve this with switching to Teleriks Rad List View instead Xamarins List View. I also didnt use last Xamarin Forms Version because of the .net standard 1.6 which is in the app currently, so I cant confirm that bug is fixed in new versions. As soon as I had Entry and ListView like its in the code above problem occurred like its displayed on image.

Comment: Try to call focus before base.OnAppearing();